# Add Radio Buttons of the same Radio Group in different table rows in android.

Tags: java, android

I creating a table dynamically in android and I want the a radio button in winner column. I have created a Radio Group and want radio buttons to be the part of the group so only one winner could be selected. But somehow, all of my radio buttons are enabled at the same time. Each buttons become independent. I have the code below.

```
public void addData() {

    numOfPlayers = currentRound.getPlayers().size();
    row = new String[numOfPlayers];
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfPlayers; i++) {
        row[i] = currentRound.getPlayers().get(i).getPlayer().getName();
    }
    col = new String[]{"Winner", "Seen", "Less", "Points"}; // get from database

    int rowCount = row.length;

    RadioGroup winnerGrp = new RadioGroup(this);

    for (int i = 0; i <= rowCount; i++) {
        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
        RadioButton winnerBtn = new RadioButton(winnerGrp.getContext());
        tableRow.setId(i);
        // create tableRow
        for (int j = 0; j <= 4; j++) {
            //create textView
            int count = 1;
            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(this);
            EditText point = new EditText(this);
            if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
                textView.setText(" ");
                tableRow.addView(textView);
            } else if (i > 0 && j == 0) {
                textView.setText(row[i - 1]); // Player Header
                tableRow.addView(textView);
            } else if (i == 0 && j != 0) {
                textView.setText(col[j - 1]); //Game Header
                tableRow.addView(textView);
            } else if (i > 0 && j == 1) {
                winnerBtn.setText(""); // Is Winner
                winnerBtn.setId(count++);
                tableRow.addView(winnerBtn);
            } else if (i > 0 && j == 2) {
                checkBox.setText(""); // Is Seen
                checkBox.setId(count++);
                tableRow.addView(checkBox);
            } else if (i > 0 && j == 3) {
                checkBox.setText(""); // Is Less
                checkBox.setId(count++);
                tableRow.addView(checkBox);
            } else if (i > 0 && j == 4) {
                point.setInputType(100); // Points
                point.setId(count++);
                tableRow.addView(point);
            }
        }
        tl.addView(tableRow);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you should add your buttons to the radiogroup.

```
winnerGrp .addView(winnerBtn)
```

Comment: I did that too..but I get this error.

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Here is the Code.
                } else if (i > 0 && j == 1) {
                    winnerBtn.setText(""); // Is Winner
                    winnerBtn.setId(count++);
                    winnerGrp .addView(winnerBtn);
                    tableRow.addView(winnerBtn);
                }

Comment: what is the code at the line where you are getting this error?

Comment: winnerGrp .addView(winnerBtn);